# In Perl, how can I extract a list of ID fields from an array of hashrefs?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

How would you push each id value in an array from an array of hashes?

I have this array:

```
@friends = [ 
   {'id' => 1, 'last_name' => 'Fo', 'first_name' => 'fa' }, 
   {'id' => 3, 'last_name' => 'pa', 'first_name' => 'pi' }, 
   {'id' => 2, 'last_name' => 'ma', 'first_name' => 'mi' } 
];
```

I want to create an array of value id like this: `@friend_ids = [1, 3, 2]`, using [push](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html).

Comment: Probably with `map` - something like `map { push @friend_ids, $$_{id} } @friends;`.  Can't test it now so I don't want to make an answer though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably have `@friends = ( ... )` and want `@friend_ids = (1, 3, 2)`. Square brackets are used for array references, not lists.
You can create such an array like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @friends = ( {id => 1, last_name => 'Fo', first_name => 'fa' },
                {id => 3, last_name => 'pa', first_name => 'pi' },
                {id => 2, last_name => 'ma', first_name => 'mi' } );
my @friend_ids;
push @friend_ids, $_->{id} for @friends;
print "@friend_ids\n";
```

But you can achieve the same without push more easily:

```
my @friend_ids = map $_->{id}, @friends;
```

If you need to remove duplicates, and sort the keys, you can use:

```
my @friend_ids = sort {$a <=> $b} uniq map $_->{id}, @friends;
```

if all IDs are numbers or just

```
my @friend_ids = sort uniq map $_->{id}, @friends;
```

if some IDs are not numeric (`uniq` is from [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/List%3a%3aMoreUtils)).

Comment: The push method would be: «`push @friend_ids, $_->{id} for @friends;`» or «`push map $_->{id}, @friend_ids;`». No reason to use both `map` and `for`.

Comment: @choroba - my bad, it is an **array references** (Square brackets) not a list.how does that change the answer?

Comment: @mamesaye: if the reference is kept in a scalar, just use `@$ref` to dereference it. If you really use an array to keep the reference, the reference is kept in its zeroth member `$array[0]`, so use `@{ $array[0] }` to dereference it.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a hash for that, so as to remove duplicates and make the result easily sortable (*if needed*):

```
my @friends = ( {id => 1, last_name => 'Fo', first_name => 'fa' },  
                {id => 3, last_name => 'pa', first_name => 'pi' },  
                {id => 2, last_name => 'ma', first_name => 'mi' } );  

my %id = map { $_->{id} => 1 } @friends;
my @friend_ids = sort { $a <=> $b } (keys %id); 
print "@friend_ids\n";
```

You can [test this script on Ideone](http://ideone.com/XKW5Q).

Comment: Since the ids are numeric, you should use numeric sort. Also, note `my %id = map { $_->{id} => 1 } @friends;`

Comment: The question does not require sort, so using an intermediate hash is resource waste.